# Call multiple functions from one Click event

Tags: javascript, html

i want call 2 actions but, if return false from first event, second will not run:

```
<input type = "button" name="Send" onClick="check();send();">
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do something like

```
<input type="button" name="Send" onClick="if(check()){send();}">
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put javascript inline like that.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascript.js"></script>
    ...more stuff in head...
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" name="Send" id="sendButton" />
  </body>
</head>
```

myJavascript.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").onclick = function() {
        if (check()) {
            send();
        }
    };
};
```

This is extremely simplified, but will get you started in the right direction...

Also, you should look into using some javascript library to help with the "plumbing", like jQuery. It makes life a bit simpler...

A smaller alternative to this:

```
<script>
    function check() {
        // return true or false...
    }
    function send() {
        // do stuff
    }
    function handleClick() {
        if (check()) {
            send();
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="button" name="Send" onclick="handleClick();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<input type = "button" name="Send" onClick="myFun();">
```

Then in your code have:

```
function myFun(){
  check();
  send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(){
       if(check()) send();
}
</script>
```

And into HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myfunc();"/>
```